# Variables not passing to a command

Tags: bash

I am wondering why the variables (`$HOST` and `$i`) are not being passed to the `timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/$HOST/$i' && echo $?` command.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=$1

for i in {0..8889}
do
    OPENPORT=$(timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/$HOST/$i' && echo $?)
    if [ "$OPENPORT" == 0 ]
    then
        echo -e "Port $i is open on $HOST.\n"
    fi
done
```

Comment: On another note: `some_command && echo $?` does not make any sense :D `echo $?` will get executed only if `some_command` is successful & thus will always echo `0` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your variables are in single quotes (`'`). Use double quotes (`"`) instead.

From [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting)

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal
>   value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not
>   occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.